# JM H.264 reference encoder, complexity calculation

Tags: c, h.264, precision

Reading the JM 18.4 reference software code I stumbled upon the following expression:

```c
return ((int) floor(nbits * p_quad->m_Qc + 0.5))
```

The types are:

```c
int nbits
int p_quad->m_Qc
```

Why would you add 0.5 and then floor the multiplication of two integers? Inspecting the results, they are the same as the multiplication alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, `floor(x + 0.5)` can be used to emulate `round(x)`.  However, this is only useful if `x` can take on non-integer values, so it seems superfluous in your case!